# Array Out of Bounds exception working with Long Values

Tags: java, security, hex, long-integer, bit

I have a function which takes as input a long value and returns a long value.

```
 static long MyBox(long S) // input is a 48-bit integer stored in 64-bit signed "long"
{
// Split I into eight 6-bit chunks
int Sa=(int)((S>>42));
int Sb=(int)((S>>36)&63);
int Sc=(int)((S>>30)&63);
int Sd=(int)((S>>24)&63);
int Se=(int)((S>>18)&63);
int Sf=(int)((S>>12)&63);
int Sg=(int)((S>>6)&63);
int Sh=(int)(S&63);
// Apply the S-boxes
byte Oa=S1Table[Sa];
byte Ob=S2Table[Sb];
byte Oc=S3Table[Sc];
byte Od=S4Table[Sd];
byte Oe=S5Table[Se];
byte Of=S6Table[Sf];
byte Og=S7Table[Sg];
byte Oh=S8Table[Sh];
// Combine answers into 32-bit output stored in 64-bit signed "long"
long O=(long)Oa<<28 | (long)Ob<<24 | (long)Oc<<20 | (long)Od<<16 | (long)Oe<<12 | (long)Of<<8 | (long)Og<<4 | (long)Oh;
return(O);
}
```

I pass a variable to this method however i get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Would anyone know why? This is how i pass it.

```
  long testPassing=0x1234567887654321L;
  long result = MyBox (testPassing);
```

and after this step I get an arrayoutofbounds exception.

Any help would be appreciated!! Thank You.

Comment: _after this step I get an arrayoutofbounds exception_ Then we want to see after this step.

Comment: Can you post the exception?  There are no arrays in the code you posted, so I'd be surprised.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 298261
 at DESPrac.SBox(DESPrac.java:131)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I meant at the step result I get the error. I don't have anything else after this step.

Comment: Is someLong an array?

Comment: Nope its a Long. Code edited

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value of your indices? they are clearly out of bounds.

Comment: @user2310289 there is further operation i need to do with the result gained. I have commented it all out to debug. hence i need to call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the value you're passing into the method.  `long testPassing=0x1234567887654321L;` is bigger than a 48 bit integer - it's actually 61 significant bits.  So when  you write `int Sa=(int)((S>>42));` you get something with 19 significant bits.  But you're using that to index your array, which presumably has only 64 entries, because (according to the comments in your code), you're looking up 6-bit chunks in it.

If you want to ignore the first 16 bits of your `long`, you could write `int Sa=(int)((S>>42)&63);` which effectively throws away everything other than the 6 bits that you're trying to isolate.

Answer (score 0):

So you have eight arrays

```
byte Oa=S1Table[Sa];
byte Ob=S2Table[Sb];
byte Oc=S3Table[Sc];
byte Od=S4Table[Sd];
byte Oe=S5Table[Se];
byte Of=S6Table[Sf];
byte Og=S7Table[Sg];
byte Oh=S8Table[Sh];
```

what is the value of Sh, ensure that your S8Table (and others) are this size - I bet they are not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the long values i initialised were longer than 16.

Comment: As per my answer, the S?Tables where not initialised only for arrays of 16?  If so please accept my answer

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. but No. Not really. It was this value that had a problem -  long testPassing=0x1234567887654321L;

Comment: Sorry I do not understand from your question, what the relevance of 16 or your input value has.  Your code is either wrong or not robust or you are still not showing us the full problem - how can we answer that?

Comment: Looks like the problem was that `(int)((S>>42))` will give a "22 bit" signed value. Even if `S` was within the uncheck 48 bit limit, the negative values would still AIOBE. / The assignment of `O` also look dodgy. Intermediate results are `int`s which are repeatedly assigned to `long`. Looks like DES, can't remember what goes on inside that. / You're best off stick with Java coding conventions. Starting a variable name with capital `O` is particularly jarring.